# Fill NA values with matching text from other observations

Tags: r

I have some data I am trying to fill out.

It looks like:

```
                      CO_1_Name Ticker2LP
 1:                  Sonic Corp      SONC
 2:                  Sonic Corp      <NA>
 3:    Baxter International Inc      <NA>
 4:    Baxter International Inc       BAX
 5: Lockheed Martin Corporation       LMT
```

There are some missing values. I want to fill in these missing values by the `Ticker2LP` ID where it is found in other rows. The expected output would be:

```
                      CO_1_Name Ticker2LP
 1:                  Sonic Corp      SONC
 2:                  Sonic Corp      SONC   # since the observation above has "SONC"
 3:    Baxter International Inc      BAX    # since the observation below has "BAX"
 4:    Baxter International Inc       BAX
 5: Lockheed Martin Corporation       LMT
```

So I want to fill in the NA`s in`Ticker2LP`when the names match from the column`CO_1_Name`. "SONC" and "BAX" were filled in since their names were found in other rows.

Data:

```
structure(list(CO_1_Name = c("Sonic Corp", "Sonic Corp", "Baxter International Inc", 
"Baxter International Inc", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", 
"Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", 
"Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Sonic Corp", "Sonic Corp", "Baxter International Inc", 
"Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", 
"Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", 
"Baxter International Inc", "Sonic Corp", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", 
"Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", 
"Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Baxter International Inc", "Sonic Corp", 
"Baxter International Inc", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Sonic Corp", 
"Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", 
"Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", 
"Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", 
"Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", 
"Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", 
"Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", 
"Sonic Corp", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", 
"Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", 
"Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", 
"Lockheed Martin Corporation", "Baxter International Inc", "Lockheed Martin Corporation", 
"Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc", "Baxter International Inc"
), Ticker2LP = c("SONC", NA, NA, "BAX", "LMT", "LMT", "MLM", 
"AP", "BAX", "LMT", "SONC", "SONC", "BAX", "BAX", NA, "LMT", 
"LMT", "LMT", NA, NA, "LMT", NA, "NOC", NA, "BAX", NA, NA, "LMT", 
"SONC", NA, "LMT", NA, NA, "BAX", "NOC", "BAX", NA, NA, NA, "BAX", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55603dbefe00>, row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, your sample data has non-unique combinations of `CO_1_Name` and `Ticker2LP`.

```
library(data.table)
unique(data[!is.na(Ticker2LP),])
                     CO_1_Name Ticker2LP
1:                  Sonic Corp      SONC
2:    Baxter International Inc       BAX
3: Lockheed Martin Corporation       LMT
4: Lockheed Martin Corporation       MLM
5:    Baxter International Inc        AP
6: Lockheed Martin Corporation       NOC
```

It sounds like you want to implement some form of "fill in the value from something nearby". One approach would be to set an ID column and do a rolling join.

```
setDT(data)[,id := 1:.N]
data[!is.na(Ticker2LP),][data , on = c("CO_1_Name","id"), roll = "nearest"][,.(CO_1_Name,Ticker2LP)]
                     CO_1_Name Ticker2LP
 1:                  Sonic Corp      SONC
 2:                  Sonic Corp      SONC
 3:    Baxter International Inc       BAX
 4:    Baxter International Inc       BAX
 5: Lockheed Martin Corporation       LMT
 6: Lockheed Martin Corporation       LMT
 7: Lockheed Martin Corporation       MLM
 8:    Baxter International Inc        AP
 9:    Baxter International Inc       BAX
10: Lockheed Martin Corporation       LMT
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    filter(complete.cases(Ticker2LP)) %>% 
    distinct
#                     CO_1_Name Ticker2LP
#1:                  Sonic Corp      SONC
#2:    Baxter International Inc       BAX
#3: Lockheed Martin Corporation       LMT
#4: Lockheed Martin Corporation       MLM
#5:    Baxter International Inc        AP
#6: Lockheed Martin Corporation       NOC
```